# How can Chrome (59.0.3071.115) be configured to NOT open a popup as a new tab?

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-Bit) seems to “suddenly” have changed how it treats popups in that it opens them as a new tab. This is at least what we observed with the update on 2017-06-26 to 27 to version 59.0.3071.115.

Even setting the popup switch to “allowed” does not appear to change this behaviour: How do we get the popup behaviour back?

Comment: I don't have that behavior (same version). Maybe it's not Chrome, but something else (but I have no idea what).

Answer (score 2):

We have this line in our (for years) running code:

```
window.open("http://www.google.de", "_blank", "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=100, left=300, width=1020, height=880");
```

Removing "toolbar=yes, " from the parameters results in Chrome 59.0.3071.115 opening it as popup again. (see http://jsfiddle.net/Pf8Rw/426/)

Comment: For us it was "location=1".  (Which is apparently an Opera-only option.)  I guess Chrome 59 has changed to opening in a tab whenever there's a parameter present that it doesn't recognize, for some reason.